# Library agnostic way to mock/fake http requests in Clojure?

Tags: http, testing, clojure, mocking

I'm looking for a project similar to [mockwebserver](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) in Clojure that allows you to programmatically define HTTP endpoints and their response by matching (parts of) the of the HTTP request (for testing purposes). I know that libraries such as [clj-http-fake](https://github.com/myfreeweb/clj-http-fake) exists but I'm looking for a library/framework agnostic way of defining the endpoints. I've created something like this myself which allows me to do:

```
(mws/given-mock-route! mock-web-server "/something" {:status 200 :content-type "application/json" :body (slurp (io/resource "responses/some.json"))})
```

But I think I read a blog or similar that such as library already exists but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now created my own open source project that accommodates this called "stub-http", it's available [here](https://github.com/johanhaleby/stub-http).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ring server, this is what you're looking for
[ring-mock](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-mock).

Comment: I know but I'm looking for a library/framework agnostic way as indicated by the question.